# Basic matrix operation in PyTorch/CuPy using GPU

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, pytorch, cupy

I have a numpy script where I do the following operation with big matrices (can go over `10000x10000` with `float` values):

```
F = (I - Q)^-1 * R
```

I first used pytorch tensors on CPU (i7-8750H) and it runs 2 times faster:

```
tensorQ = torch.from_numpy(Q)
tensorR = torch.from_numpy(R)
sub= torch.eye(a * d, dtype=float) - tensorQ
inv= torch.inverse(sub)
tensorF = torch.mm(inv, tensorR)
F = tensorF.numpy()
```

Now I'm trying to execute it on GPU (1050Ti Max-Q) to see if I can get another speedup but the code run slower than numpy version (I've already installed CUDA and cuDNN). Maybe pytorch it's not even the best library to do this kind of things, but I'm learning it now and I thought it could help me:

```
dev = torch.device('cuda')

tensorQ = torch.from_numpy(Q).to(dev)
tensorR = torch.from_numpy(R).to(dev)
sub= torch.eye(a * d, dtype=float).to(dev) - tensorQ
inv= torch.inverse(sub).to(dev)
tensorF = torch.mm(inv, tensorR).cpu()
F = tensorF.numpy()
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
I also tried using CuPy but it's still slow:

```
Q = cp.array(matrixQ)
R = cp.array(matrixR)
sub = cp.identity(attacker * defender) - matrixQ
inv = cp.linalg.inv(sub)
F = cp.matmul(inv, matrixR)
F = cp.asnumpy(matrixF)
```

Probably the overhead of memory allocation is just too big compared to the computation of few operations.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that includes generating representative/example data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You mean how I create the matrices? I didn't posted it because it's long and complex. My answer was actually more general, I was asking if what I wrote it's sufficient to run on GPU. I also looked in the windows task manager and GPU has only some peaks and I don't understand if it's running in the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are using GPU, the computer needs to allocate memory through CPU then the GPU will allocate memory for the array. GPU is used for large Matri x calculation. If your matrix is not big, stick to use CPU to do calculation.